# Cannot connect to Apollo GraphQL server on Android Release [react native]

Tags: android, react-native, http, graphql, apollo

```
    httpURI = 'http://17.25.16.68:4000/graphql' //example
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: httpURI });
    const client = new ApolloClient({ link:httpLink, cache: new InMemoryCache() });
```

The connection works on debug mode, but when I run it on release, no connection is made.

Do I need to enable outgoing connections somewhere in the Android release config?

Comment: Maybe.. this problem is HTTP Error Please refer https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24627#issuecomment-492159371

Answer (score 0):

This is something that worked for me. apparently android pie doesn't allow network requests to URLs without https.

```
<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This file allowed android for reaching http requests.
In android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml add the line below

```
<application 
   .
   .
   .
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   .
   .
   .
>
</application>
```